# Regular expression syntax

Tags: finite-automata, regular-expressions

am a little confused by regular expression to convert to NFAs. 
am actually test using

http://www.regexr.com/

but some of regular expression like

> a*+ab

is that mean (a*)+ is that correct ..

also

> ab*+bc*

how can i get b*+ or that mean (ab*)+ i do not know how to get it ?

however is the (a*)+ is the same a+ , i think will match the same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the examples you give, the site you're using appears to be using "+" to mean "or". Other people use "|" for that but both notations are common enough that they can be called standard.

Comment: so '+' mean in the examples 'or' boolean operator not one or more item of the preceding

Comment: @Yassine Yes, that's what I just wrote.